# Modify Key-Bindings in Emacs ESS mode

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I just started using [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org/) mode for writing R code in Emacs and
I realize that every time I write and underscore `_` it is transformed into R's     `<-`.

Since I use underscore in variables names, I find this key-binding annoying. 
How do I disable it?

I cannot find an answer in the documentation, and looking at the files in the `ESS/lisp` directory I am getting lost.

Answer (score 1):

Just put

```
(ess-toggle-underscore nil)             ; disable 'smart underscore'
```

in your `.emacs` file